# Remove export option for particular table in zf-datagrid

Tags: zend-framework, datagrid

I want to remove out the datagrid export option ('pdf', 'csv','excel','word' etc..) for some

specific `table`  in the datagrid of zend framework . Its now by default coming for every

table attached to the project , How can i do this ? Thanks . posting the code of the datagrid

helper below

```
public function dataGrid($sql){

    $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->view->baseUrl('grid/styles/styles.css'));
        $this->view->setEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH. '/configs/grid.ini', 'production');
        $grid = Bvb_Grid::factory('Table', $config, 'grid');
        $grid->setExport(array());
        $backendName = Zend_Cache::$standardBackends[0];
        $frontendName  = Zend_Cache::$standardFrontends[0];
        $frontendOptions = array('automatic_serialization'=> true);
        $backendOptions = array('auto_refresh_fast_cache'=> true);
        $cache = Zend_Cache::factory($frontendName,
                             $backendName,$frontendOptions,$backendOptions);
        $grid->setExport(array('pdf', 'csv','excel','word'));
        $grid->addFiltersRenderDir(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/helpers/Filters/', 'Filters');
        $grid->setPaginationInterval(array(100 =>100, 200 => 200, 500 => 500, 1000 => 1000));
        $grid->setUseKeyEventsOnFilters(true);
        $grid->query($sql);       
        return $grid;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$grid->setGridColumns($grid_columns);
$grid->setExport(array()); 
$gd = $grid->deploy();
```

You can set the export option into `null` by passing a null array to the `setExport` function

Comment: Oh yeah , i have to add that particular option in specific views ,and the grid options are in the config file . thanks